# Call load using a div id that has been passed into a function, div id is a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html, load

I am dynamically creating divs within a jquery accordion that are loaded with data as when the user clicks on the accordion title. I have this all working except that when I pass the div id into the load details method, the call to .load() does not work. What can I do to fix this? It seems like a simple javascript string eval would work but I can not find what I am looking for.

Code:
Here is the basic function:

```
function loadDetails(div_id) {
   var load_string = "ajax/get_details.aspx";
   $(div_id).load(load_string);
 }
```

This function is called correctly on the click event and the div_id is passed in correctly but the load function is not working. If I use code like this it work correctly:

```
$('#test').load(load_string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#" + div_id).load(load_string);
```

I'm assuming the div_id being passed in is missing the pound?

Comment: yes thanks, i knew it would be something simple. I tried something similar but added single quotes around the whole thing and that doesn't work!

But this works! SO thanks!

Comment: No problem. Please be sure to flag answers when someone has resolved your issue. You can do so by selecting the checkmark beside the up/down arrows on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

maby: `$('#' + div_id).load(load_string);`

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/